# C api compatible with 32 and 64 bit integers simultaneously

Tags: c, api, gcc, platform

I have a C api to a shared (or static) library using int types and would like to upgrade to int64_t.
Doing so, I want to make sure that my previous users can still upgrade the library and do not have to rewrite their whole codes.

I have come up with the solution on this gist and which replicates my code behavior (using callbacks): https://git.io/vMy8G —

#### example.c

```
// User defines a different type
#define MYLONG int

#include "interface.h"
#include "stdio.h"

// User callback using his own type
int test(const int i, const my_long var, const int j) {
    printf("i   = %d\n",i);
    printf("var = %lld\n",(long long) var);
    printf("j   = %d\n",j);
    printf("%lld\n", 2LL*var-11);
    return var - 7;
}

int main() {
    // This is what user sees
    api_func functionPtr = &test;
    define_callback(functionPtr);

    // Simulate callback call
    call_callback();
    return 0;
}
```

#### interface.h

```
#pragma once

// MYLONG is defined differently internally and externally (before importing this file)
typedef MYLONG my_long;

// Callback definition
typedef int (*api_func)(const int, const my_long, const int); // surround by int to test alignment issues

void define_callback(api_func fptr);
void call_callback();
```

#### internal.c

```
#define MYLONG long long

#include "interface.h"

// Callback handling
api_func callback_ptr = 0;

void define_callback(api_func fptr) {
    callback_ptr = fptr;
}

void call_callback() {
    (*callback_ptr)(1000, 100000, 100);
    (*callback_ptr)(1000, 10000000000, 100); // will overflow when user uses int
}
```

The library would always be compiled with `#define MYLONG int64_t` while user will either use `#define MYLONG int64_t` or `#define MYLONG int` (this would be done automatically depending on some other settings). The latest define would ensure backwards compatibility.

Valgrind checks pass with all builds.

My question is the following:

- Is it safe?
- Am I relying on any non-guaranteed behavior of the compiler?
- Why would it (or wouldn't it) work? (any paragraph about this in the norm?)
- Do you see any better way of doing this?

Note that I would like to avoid writing 64 bit versions of all my functions if possible. Also, this has to work on Linux (gcc), Mac (gcc) and Windows (Visual Studio).

Comment: Edit : I have simplified the question. Also note that the macro definition is here for the purpose of having a simple minimal example. This is not what will be exposed to the end user.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for improving this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Is it safe?

No.  User in *example.c* sets `callback_ptr` to :

```
int test(const int i, const int var, const int j)
```

... and `call_callback()` calls that as:

```
int (*api_func)(const int, const int64_t, const int)
```

This is UB (not overflow) whenever `int` is not the same type as `int64_t`.

2. Am I relying on any non-guaranteed behavior of the compiler?

Yes.

3. Why would it (or wouldn't it) work? (any paragraph about this in the norm?)

It is *undefined behavior* (UB).  Code is calling a function with one signature, yet the function may have an incompatible one.

4. Do you see any better way of doing this?

Yes.
A. Certainly do not code with mis-matched-able function signatures.
B. In the end, I think OP needs a new approach.  I would recommend **adding** a function `define_callback64()` and then have the user call `define_callback64()` with `int (*f)(const int, int64_t, const int)` or `define_callback()` as before.  `call_callback()` can then use the one that was set.

---

Code comments

> Note that I would like to avoid writing 64 bit versions of all my functions if possible.

OP wants "would like to upgrade to int64_t" yet "avoid writing 64 bit versions of all my functions".   This is most curious and apparently contradictory.

Perhaps re-write `internal.c` as `int64_t` and then call select call back functions.

The 3 `const` in `typedef int (*api_func)(const int, const my_long, const int)` serve no purpose.

OP seems to assume `int` is 32-bit given the title.  Better to write code that does not assume this.  `int` is *at least* 16-bit.  OTOH, I do not see a great problem assuming `int` is not wider than `int64_t`, but even that is not defined by the C spec.

OP also seem to also assume `long long` is `int64_t` given code `#define MYLONG long long` yet "library would always be compiled with `#define MYLONG int64_t`".  OP needs to use types correctly and consistently in code and documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @chux. Indeed, long long is not necessarily the same as int64_t. I just made a simple example for demonstration purposes. By the way, how would you achieve the callback selection given that the header can be included more than once (so cannot create an initialized global variable here) ? [the shared library would need to know which version user decided to use and unless having an explicit function call I don't see how you could "notify" it]

Comment: @mgb Agree, I'm all for simple examples, yet `#define MYLONG long long`  introduced an unnecessary  inconsistency and thus a more complex review of the post.   `#define MYLONG int64_t` would have agreed with the text of the post.  OTOH, maybe you really wanted `long long`, and not necessarily fixed 64-bit integers.  What is the coding goal: `long long`, `int64_t`, either, something else?  Maybe go for `intmax_t`?  Many choices.

Comment: "the shared library would need to know which version user decided to use and unless having an explicit function call I don't see how you could "notify" it" --> right.  "internal.c" code could know what type is needed by what noting what function was called `define_callback()`, `define_callback64()`, `define_callback_longlong()`, etc.  One of those functions would have been called only once prior to any `call_callback()`.  Alternative: If using C99 or later, code could explore use of `_Generic`.

Comment: Thanks for your help @chux but as I said, for compatibility purposes, I don't want users to redefine their define callback calls. The switch has to be smooth for them. I could redefine function names using macros depending on user architecture selection but I don't like it for debug purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do to write the best ported code is to not rely on size. and if you do explicitly use `uint32_t` or `int64_t`.

Use native `int` or `long` otherwise.

Requesting the user to define macros for something that is totally unnecessary is error prone and wrong.

Comment: My current api uses int (which is 32 bit even on 64 bit systems) and I want to use int64_t instead because this is needed to handle some larger problems. If Iswitch to int64_t this will raise tons of unnecessary warnings for users.

Note that the example does not illustrate the final api but just simplifies the problem. I will not ask user to define a macro to switch from one model to another.